# Spring is trying to subclass a record component when aop is present

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aspectj, spring-aop

I have a spring boot application in which I make use of aspects. Recently, I tried converting my `@ConfigurationProperties` classes to java records, but it fails with `"Cannot subclass final class {..}Properties"`. It seems spring is trying to make cglib proxies for my records, which obviously fail. Is there any way to tell spring not to make proxies for specific classes?

Edit:

The properties:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "foo.bar")
public record MyProperties(String a,
                           String b) {

}
```

Stacktrace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class {...}.MyProperties: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class {...}.MyProperties
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:209)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:110)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.createProxy(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:478)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:342)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:437)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1790)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602)
... 48 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class {...}.MyProperties
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:660)
at org.springframework.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
at org.springframework.cglib.core.ClassLoaderAwareGeneratorStrategy.generate(ClassLoaderAwareGeneratorStrategy.java:57)
at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:358)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generate(Enhancer.java:585)
at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:131)
at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:319)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:572)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:419)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.createProxyClassAndInstance(ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.java:57)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:206)
... 55 common frames omitted
```

Edit 2: A minimal, reproducible example: https://github.com/moxaj/aspect-mcve-2

Comment: I am curious as to why you think its AOP that is causing it problems?  Perhaps include the stacktrace, and code of how you are creating ConfigurationProperties using record

Comment: Without seeing your actual classes this would be quite impossible to answer, but I suspect you also have something like `@Valid` on there or using JSR-330 for validation of properties. So please add some code as currently I would say there is too little information to answer this question.

Comment: Is this even possible ?

Comment: @M.Deinum added an mcve, see my latest edit

Comment: Your pointcut is applying too broadly. My AspectJ is a little rusty, but I suspect that you want `@within` rather than `@target`.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I just realized I missed an `&&`, but still: I have both within (my domain) and @target (so that it only applies to @Service annotated classes). Why would that apply to a @ConfigurationProperties?

Comment: Your existing `within` is fine. It's `@target` that I think should be `@within`, making the whole pointcut `"within(foo.bar..*) && @within(org.springframework.stereotype.Service)"`

Comment: @ViktorMagyari, how about some feedback to my answer? I solved your problem a week ago.

Comment: @kriegaex hey, i'm sure your solution works as well, but I simply ended up dropping the first `@within`, thus not restricting it to my domain (hopefully the spring internals do not define any services..). So the end result is simply `@within(org.springframework.stereotype.Service)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cloned your [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) repository. Thanks, that was helpful.

Please note that Java records are implicitly final. Therefore, Spring AOP cannot subclass them in order to create dynamic proxies.

You need to change

```java
@Pointcut("within(foo.bar..*) @target(org.springframework.stereotype.Service)")
```

(please also note the syntax error, missing `&&`) to

```java
@Pointcut(
  "within(foo.bar..*) && " +
  "@target(org.springframework.stereotype.Service) && " +
  "!@within(org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties)"
)
```

I just added a few line breaks in order to make the pointcut more readable.